# Google Drive SDK application to upload file

Tags: android, google-drive-api, noclassdeffounderror, google-play-services

I am trying to use the Google Drive SDK to upload files, but I am getting a pop up saying `unfortunately your application has stopped`. This is due to a `NoClassDefFoundError`. I also made sure to include the play services jar and check it in the order and export tab as well.

This is the excpetion:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 4906): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.common.AccountPicker
E/AndroidRuntime( 4906):        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.
newChooseAccountIntent(GoogleAccountCredential.java:253)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4906):        at com.example.informationretreival.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4906):        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4906):        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4906):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2147)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4906):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4906):        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:144)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4906):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4906):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4906):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4906):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5074)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4906):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4906):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4906):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4906):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4906):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(  771):   Force finishing activity com.example.informationretreival/.MainActivity
```

I am following the quickstart on the [developer website](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android#step_1_generate_the_signing_certificate_fingerprint_sha1) I have literally just copied the code. I would expect the quickstart example to work. Someone please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

In your Android application configuration page, select **Google APIs (Google Inc.) (API 17)** for **Compile with**. Also, it would work more stable on real phone than virtual device since virtual device doesn't have play store.

Comment: I have the Build target as API 17 Google APIs. So, I dont think that is the issue.